# If Hastar only wants food, then why can't he trade it for gold which he has unlimited?

Tags: plot-explanation, character, tumbbad

In the movie *Tumbbad* Hastar attacks anyone who takes his gold, but he needs food. So why does he attack whoever offers him food? Why can't he be a good man and offer gold and try not to kill the person who provides food to him?

The whole movie is based on this, that's why I'm asking.

Comment: Gold is *kinda* expensive.

Comment: Because he views the gold as being more important than the  life of a mere mortal, possibly. After all, he could consider the all of the gold and all of the food of his mother-earth rightfully his.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hastar is not a human or even a cursed human. He is a demon god. He is cursed by all the other gods and hence living in protection of his mother's womb.

Previously he tried to steal all the gold and food from his mother but could only take gold.

Gold here does not mean anything for him. He just wants every object to be his. It does have value for humans that's why they are tricking him by giving him food and trying to get as many coins as they can.

He does not know the language or transaction and neither wants to kill anyone. But when he touches a human, his curse of living eternal life as diseased is transmitted to them.